# CSS three inline elements with align from left to right, how to occupy all available width

Tags: css, inline, text-align

I have a slider, with a div that contains the controls previous, start/stop sliding, next.

I set "text-align" to left, center and right, respectively, and display to "inline". I have no idea, now, how to fill the whole width.

Here is the markup:

```
<div id="external_promo_controls">
  <div id="promo_previous"></div>
  <div id="promo_auto_controls"></div>
  <div id="promo_next"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#external_promo_controls div{
    display: inline;
}
#promo_previous {text-align: left;}
#promo_auto_controls {text-align: center;}
#promo_next {text-align: right;}
```

I guess I could have it done with floating elements, however I got quite a mess trying to have a correct combination of elements being on one line and centering the element in the middle. I’d like to avoid positioning elements with pixel value, since it would break as soon as I change text, font, or size or the container, which are all events that will eventually occur.

Comment: do all three child divs need to have equal size or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple to use floats - this fiddle should set you on the right path:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4paq/

New example with DIVs containg a link with a hover state.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4paq/1/

Comment: Actually I found out it has a problem. Hover on element is not recognized. Any idea how that can be possible? Never seen anything like that happening

Comment: Do you want the whole of each of the three to be a link? I had assumed you would be placing a link inside each DIV.

Comment: That’s what I did, the link is inside each div... but no hover! :(

Comment: Html markup same as above, each div has an internal link (generated by jquery) in the form
    '<a href="">control name</a>'
Here is the css

#external_promo_controls div{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

#promo_auto_controls {text-align: center;}
#promo_next {text-align: right;}

    #external_promo_controls a {
        color: #5F7E92;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    #external_promo_controls a:active {
        color: #5F7E92; 
    }
    
    #external_promo_controls a:hover {
        color: #2F4EA2;
        text-decoration: underline overline;    
    }

Comment: Please post your code in a fiddle on jsfiddle.net, including your jQuery.

Comment: @DavidTonarini - I've added a new link to my answer above showing links with a working hover state. Nothing fancy about this so please re-accept my answer if this is good for you.

Comment: I found out the problem is the dynamically generated element, so it is somewhere in my jquery (I’m using an external code, bx slider)
I accepted your answer, therefore, since my problem is in something different, and open a different question for that. Thanks again.

Comment: I don’t seem to be able to reproduce the error, by the way, so no idea what’s actually happening lol

Comment: I wasn’t able to reproduce it on jsfiddle, but here is a simplified page: http://demitogroup.comuv.com/d_store/copia.html

If I use firebug to disable the floating it works, but when elements are floating hover are not recognized

Comment: An example of the problem is here: http://demitogroup.comuv.com/d_store/copia.html

I posted a new question about this, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146022/hover-not-recognized-on-floating-dynamically-generated-element-bx-slider

Answer (score 0):

try this. I am not sure it will work or not but suppose all three inner divs has width of `100px` each then

`outerDiv` specify the width to be 300px with no margin and padding

`innerDiv` width:100px  and margin and padding are 0px and float : left.

if you want to specify margin and padding then summation of all three innerDiv's `width + padding + margin + border` * 3 should be the width of the outer div.