# Hover not recognized on floating dynamically generated element (bx slider)

Tags: css, hover, css-float, dynamically-generated, bxslider

I am using bx Slider, using external controls for previous and next slide.
All is working fine. However, I am using floating elements for the controls, since I want them in a line and filling the whole containing div (as in this question [CSS three inline elements with align from left to right, how to occupy all available width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142980/css-three-inline-elements-with-align-from-left-to-right-how-to-occupy-all-avail) )

However, the controls are generated dynamically by bxSlider, and for some strange reason, if the elements are floating hover is not recognized

Here is an example page: http://demitogroup.comuv.com/d_store/copia.html

If I turn the float off with firebug to #external_promo_controls div hover is recognized again.

If the links are not generated dynamically the problem does not show up.

On Chrome the same happens.

I have totally no idea about what is happening.

Could try to figure out something avoiding to use float elements, but then I will be back again to my first question...

Comment: If this helps, I found out that the "next" button does recognize hover, IF the cursor is exactly at the end of it. Personally, this does confuse me even more, anyway

Comment: In a developer console, check the computed width of your element. Sounds like it may be collapsing, in which case you may need to either specify a specific width/height or add a placeholder element inside the button.

Comment: hey can you undo the change in your may be i can give you better output i just refresh the page and it start working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect your floated element to fill the whole space, try setting it to display:block explicitly, if it is not already. If that doesn't work, try setting a large z-index on it to guarantee nothing hidden is getting above it.

Comment: That works, as soon as I explicitely declare the height property. I honestly do not understand why this happens though. The hover is on the child element, so why in the world is parent property influencing how they behave, through it does not influence how they appear?
That’s quite strange to me. Well, anyway, that solves the problem so thanks a lot.